# Ebean, Play 2 Framework with Java

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

So... been learning Play 2. Pretty cool really, however... ridiculously limited docs and detailed explanation. Anyway, that's more of a side note.

I'm using Ebean to retrieve data such as:

```
public static List<DataType> findInvolving(String data) {
    return find.where()
        .eq("column_name", data)
        .findList();
}
```

The question is, how the hell do you do a NOT EQUAL too??

Checked this out too but to no avail 
   - http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html

Comment: Are you not using an IDE with autocompletion that shows you [javadocs](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/) for all methods? You can easily find methods like [`.ne()`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/ExpressionList.html#ne(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) that way.

Comment: +1 to @zapl, although even failing that, the doc you are looking for is the top search result for the query 'ebean api not equal'. There is even a post on SO with the title, 'Java EBean Not Equal' with the answer to your question in their question statement.

Comment: Care to provide a link then bright spark, instead of just making a random statement.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this... visit http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Filter.html

Answer (score 0):

here is a list of all expressions for Ebeans:
https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/Expr.html

you can use `.ne()`